# When building a custom ajax form in Rails, what is the proper data to send to to the controller to get it to respond to Json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to build a custom ajax form (not interested in using the Rails out of the box solution):

```
    $('form.ajaxForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this),
          formValues = getFormValues($form),
          formUrl = $form.attr('action');


        $.post(formUrl, {
          data : formValues,
          contentType: "application/json",
          success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
             // do success here
          }
        });
      });

var getFormValues = function($form){
    var values = {};
    var valuesArray = $form.serializeArray();
    for(var i = 0, max = valuesArray.length; i < max; i++){
      var value = valuesArray[i];
      values[value.name] = value.value
    };
    return values;
  };
```

I do want to use Rails 3's ability to respond differently when it receives a json request such as:

```
def create
    @registration = Registration.new(params[:registration])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @registration.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
```

For some reason, Rails cant process my request during the post, and doesn't respond to json.  What in the http headers tells it to respond to json, and what is the proper way to post this data?

Comment: I believe you may need to use dataType in your ajax call to specify for the server to return json. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Make sure you are sending the CSRF token as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Rails API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to) I came across this tidbit:

> Rails determines the desired response format from the HTTP Accept
>   header submitted by the client.

jQuery's `$.ajax` call has an `accepts` setting that can be used to set the value for this header but I believe that using `dataType` will automatically configure this for you.